# IE 9 Cookie Problem

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, internet-explorer-9

I am having a cookie problem that occurs only in IE 9(Maybe in 8 never tested it really).

I am using the [Jquery Cookie Plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)  to store some user settings.

```
  $.cookie("userSetting1", "true", { expires: 999, path: '/' });
```

So I am saving the cookie at the root path so it should be available on all pages. This of course works perfectly on firefox 4 and google chrome.

From the limited tools(web developer tools) that IE has it seems that it is still trying to save the cookie per page basis not per site basis.

Any other tools that I can use to look into the cookie better(something like firecookies) or any suggestions why it does not save everything to the root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out when you go to IE 9 options and tell it to "Delete Cookies" it does not delete them.

I had to use this to delete the old cookies that where said at the page level and not the root level.

Comment: so how did you delete the cookies in the end?

Comment: @gabor - Did not see this. I had to get a 3rd party app(forgot the name of it). That showed me all the cookies and had to use it delete it.